# Latest Autopilot clusters not support cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a GKE Autopilot cluster on 1.21.5-gke.1302 and I'm migrating some services from an older account to this cluster. One of my helm charts is deploying a CronJob with `cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict=false` annotation set on the Job spec. The Job will not run, and gets the error `Error creating: admission webhook "policycontrollerv2.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Policy Controller rejected the request because it violates one or more policies: {"[denied by autogke-node-affinity-selector-limitation]":["Auto GKE disallows use of cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict=false annotation on workloads"]}`

This exact same CronJob and Job spec are running in our older cluster which is still on `1.20.10-gke.1600`. Is this something that changed recently in GKE Autopilot? Is there a solution other than removing the annotation from the Job? The annotation is hard-coded in the helm template, and it does seem like something we'd want to have set on the Job.